# Why does this compile in C and C++ except in my Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c

In:

```
int main()
{
    char* const fooCode = "function foo(x, y) { return x + y; }";

}
```

The error I get in Visual Studio is:

```
Error (active)  E0144   a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *const"
```

Technically string literals are const, so this makes sense to me. However I found this in C code meaning it's legitimate C code. And when I tested in a C++ compiler online However on online compilers such as [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler#) it compiles fine. How can it compile?

Comment: All string literals in C++ have the type `const char[N]`.

Comment: @NathanOliver How does it compile in two online compilers I tried online, both C and C++?

Comment: The link you provided does not point to a working example but if you are using g++ it has non-conforming extensions to allows the code to compile.  I always suggest using the `-pedantic-errors` compiler flag when compiling to force strict conformance with the c++ standard

Comment: @Zebrafish: Re “How does it compile in two online compilers I tried online, both C and C++?”: Some C compilers are not C standard compilers, and some C++ compilers are not standard C++ compilers. C and C++ are not just one language. Each is a family of many languages, some of which are standard C with extensions, and some of which are variations from the standard. Nobody is in charge of what C alone is or what C++ alone is. The C standard is merely one instance of a C language—one that many people use, but still just one possibility, and the same for C++.

Comment: your link to " it compiles fine" produces a warning that should be treated as error. The warning message mentions that the code only passed due to the compiler being lax

Comment: also make sure you check for warnings.  For instance in older versions of GCC you get `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]` for the code.  This can also be elevated into an error using `-Werror` to turn warnings into errors

Comment: use `-pedantic-errors` to get the proper error

Comment: I've added another dupe target that talks about how it compiles and the warnings it gives you even though it should be errors.  TL;DR: backwards compatibility.